# How can I get my mom a dependent visa for Poland?

Tags: schengen, dependent-visa, poland, bangladeshi-citizens

I am from Bangladesh, and recently I got a job offer from Google, Warsaw as a software engineer.  My mother is a 64 year old widow, has some medical conditions, and needs to be cared for. Now I need to relocate to Poland for the job.  I searched Poland's embassy website and found they have a policy called “RIGHT TO FAMILY REUNIFICATION,” but it’s only applicable for spouses and children, not for parents.  In this situation, how can I relocate to Poland with my mom? Would you please give me some suggestions and guidelines? My father passed away long ago and I am the only support of my mom. I am apprehensive about this. Is there any way for us?